# Override nested parameters using kedro run CLI command

Tags: python, command-line-interface, kedro

I am using nested parameters in my `parameters.yml` and would like to override these using runtime parameters for the `kedro run` CLI command:

```
train:
    batch_size: 32
    train_ratio: 0.9
    epochs: 5
```

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
kedro run --params  train.batch_size:64,train.epochs:50
```

the values for epoch and batch_size are those from the `parameters.yml`. How can I override these parameters with the cli command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The additional parameters get passed into the `KedroContext` object via `load_context(Path.cwd(), env=env, extra_params=params)` in `kedro_cli.py`. Here you can see that there's a callback (protected) function called `_split_params` which splits the key-value pairs on `:`.

This `_split_params` first splits string on commas (to get multiple params) and then on colons. Actually adding a print/logging statement of what gets passed into `extra_params` will show you something like:

```py
{'train.batch_size': 64, 'train.epochs': 50}
```

I think you have a couple options:

1. Un-nesting the params. That way you will override them correctly.
2. Adding custom logic to `_split_params` in `kedro_cli.py` to create a nested dictionary on `.` characters which gets passed into the func mentioned above. I think you can reuse a lot of the existing logic.

NB: This was tested on `kedro==0.16.2`.

NB2: The way `kedro` splits out nested params is using the `_get_feed_dict` and `_add_param_to_feed_dict` functions in `context.py`. Specifically, `_add_param_to_feed_dict` is a recursive function that unpacks a dictionary and formats as `"{}.{}".format(key, value)`. IMO you can use the logic from here.

Comment: I was hoping that there is a cli syntax which would allow this but I already feared that I'll have to go with your suggested second option when dealing with nested parameters. Thank you @napoleon_borntoparty confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another way.
I add to my Kedro project file `run.py` and override `KedroContext` and `ConfigLoader`.

Now I can use in CLI something like that `kedro run .. --params "train_kwargs_max_epochs:1"` and it will be converted as `train_kwargs.max_epochs = 1`.

So I can use in my pipeline `params:train_kwargs` and in the node use it to init Trainer: `Trainer(**train_kwargs)`.

I would be happy to provide full source code if anybody is interested in it.
Thing is the current code are deeply integrated with my customer's sources and I need time to separate it and publish.